Who is J. T., the dedicatee of The City and the Pillar?
The front matter of Gore Vidal's The City and the Pillar (1948, rev. 1965, 1995) includes this dedication: "For the memory of J. T." Who is J. T.? Why did Vidal choose them as the dedicatee? Does the dedication reveal or reflect anything about the plot and themes of this novel?

Vidal later confirmed that the "J.T." in question was James Trimble, a schoolfriend and his childhood love. Expanding on this point, Vidal wrote about Trimble in his 1995 memoir that:

He saw himself in Jimmie and Jimmie in himself; it was this twinning
that he was attracted to, and claimed that he would never find again
in his life. Vidal is explicit and loving in his descriptions of
Jimmie. He remembers his blonde curls, his sweat that smelled like
honey, his athletic body. Vidal’s language to describe their
relationship is elevated, intense, Platonic. Vidal writes that the
only time he experienced “wholeness” with another person was when
having sex with Jimmie. He claimed, “I have never had an affair with
anyone. Sex, yes. Friendships, yes. The two combined? No. Jimmie, of
course, was something else—me.”

Jacquelyn Ardam, "The Gore Vidal Papers: A Love Story", the Toast, 2016.
Trimble was killed in World War II at Iwo Jima in 1945, "a tragedy that haunted Vidal for the rest of his life". Indeed
Vidal is said to have chosen his gravesite because it was positioned between the graves of two people who were important in his life: Henry Adams, the historian and writer; and his boyhood friend Jimmie Trimble.
Vidal wrote The City and the Pillar in 1946, barely a year after Jimmie's death. It would be natural to assume that it is in part inspiration and homage to Trimble. Like Trimble the protagonist of the novel was athletic and masculine, in contrast to many contemporary depictions of homosexuals, and Jim and Bob were boyhood lovers. There is an echo of the separation that was produced by military service in World War II: Trimble left Vidal when he joined the army, and similarly Jim and his later lover, Paul, are parted when they both enlist. Trimble's early death, however, avoided any role in him inspiring the novel's denouement.
